# Span value inside a style value

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

this maybe a very stupid question, but is this possibe ?

well i have a sort of a slider on a html page.
this is what it shows up like now:

```
<p>Illustrator</p>
      <div class="w3-light-grey w3-round-xlarge w3-small">
        <div class="w3-container w3-center w3-round-xlarge w3-teal" style="width:75%">75%</div>
      </div>
```

This shows up a bar,

well what want to achieve is if its possible to change that value 75% to my script data :

```
style="width:75%">
```

like i have a script, it retrieves values from my server:

```
  var input = "10;11;15";

var arr = input.split(";");


 document.getElementById("humid").innerHTML = (arr[0 ]);
```

this shows up my data just normal

```
<span id="humid">0</span>
```

what i want to do is something like this, but i don't know how:

I want this value from style="width:75%"> to be the humid value.
so if my humid value is 50% the width goes 50%

i did try this but no result

```
style="width:humid+%">
or style="width:(humid)+%">
```

i'm still learning,
regards

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>TESt</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
html,body,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif}
</style>
<body class="w3-light-grey">
        <p>Original</p>
      <div class="w3-light-grey w3-round-xlarge w3-small">
        <div class="w3-container w3-center w3-round-xlarge w3-teal" style="width:75%">75%</div>


 
          </div>
          <p>Media</p>
          <div class="w3-light-grey w3-round-xlarge w3-small">
            <div class="w3-container w3-center w3-round-xlarge w3-teal"  style="#humid">0</div>
            
          
  


</body>




<script>
  var input = "10;11;15";

var arr = input.split(";");

//alert(arr[1 ]);
 document.getElementById("humid").innerHTML = (arr[0]);
 document.getElementById("temp").innerHTML = (arr[1 ]);
 document.getElementById("uv").innerHTML = (arr[2 ]);
</script>
</html>
```

Retrieve my input:

```
    function readForestall() {
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("ForestAll").innerHTML =
            this.responseText;
          }
        };
        xhttp.open("GET", "readFORESTALL", false);
        xhttp.send();
        }



 setInterval(function() {
      readForestall();
    }, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question right, you want to change the `width` of an element based on a variable you receive. In that case you can [change the inline style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ElementCSSInlineStyle/style) with JavaScript. You just need to grab the element and set the style by assigning values to the properties of the element's `style` property.

If you want to change the width, you can use the following:

```js
element.style.width = '50%'
```

It sets the width to 50%. You can also include a variable like this:

```js
const width = 50
element.style.width = `${width}%`
```

I've created a snippet below where you can set the value by using an input and it updates both the width and the content of that div. You can click on the "Run code snippet button" and see the result in live.

```js
const barLeft = document.querySelector('#bar-left');
const barRight = document.querySelector('#bar-right');
const input = document.querySelector('[name="width"]');
const error = document.querySelector('.error');

input.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  const widthLeft = Number(e.target.value);
  const widthRight = 100 - widthLeft;

  if (widthLeft < 0 || widthLeft > 100) {
    error.textContent =
      "We don't do that here. Width must be between 0 and 100.";
    return;
  }
  
  error.textContent = '';
  barLeft.textContent = `${widthLeft}%`;
  barLeft.style.width = `${widthLeft}%`;
  barRight.textContent = `${widthRight}%`;
  barRight.style.width = `${widthRight}%`;
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.outer {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.inner {
  background-color: lightcoral;
  box-shadow: 0 -4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.inner--blue {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.controls {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

input {
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
}

.error {
  color: #d32f2f;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner" id="bar-left" style="width: 75%">75%</div>
  <div class="inner inner--blue" id="bar-right" style="width: 25%">25%</div>
</div>
<div class="controls">
  <label for="width">First bar's width:</label>
  <input type="number" name="width" id="width" min="5" max="95" value="75" />
</div>
<div class="error"></div>
```

*Update:* Updated your example below. Make sure you close your tags, and check out how to add `id`s to elements.

```html
<body class="w3-light-grey">
  <p>Media</p>
  <div class="w3-light-grey w3-round-xlarge w3-small">
    <div class="w3-container w3-center w3-round-xlarge w3-teal" id="humid">
      0
    </div>
  </div>
  div>

  <script>
    var input = '10;11;15';
    var arr = input.split(';');

    // update the content of the div with ID "humid"
    document.getElementById('humid').textContent = arr[0];
    // change the width of the div with ID "humid"
    document.getElementById('humid').style.width = `${arr[0]}%`;
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: many thanks, but its complicated for me.  what i really need is a progress bar with the values i receive from my devices.. style="width:75%">  i want this bit "width:75%" changed to my value from "document.getElementById("humid").innerHTML = (arr[0 ]);"  so that the 75% changes to the value from my humidity device.

Comment: That's explained above and you can find these two lines in the snippet: `barLeft.textContent = \`${widthLeft}%\`; barLeft.style.width = \`${widthLeft}%\`;`

Comment: i did try it but i cant manage to get it working with my code. can u show me with my own posted code ?

Comment: If you can update your original question where the `span` is inside the `div`s, I can give it a try. It's not really clear for me at the moment.

Comment: ok i posted the full test template, look in script at the end. thats how i get my devices

Comment: I've just updated it, hopefully it works.

Comment: i dont know why my message did not appear, but many thanks and it works perfect!! exactly what i needed. thanks for your time !!

Comment: i have 1 quick question, it works as expected with the custom input, but when i want to change the imput it doesnt work anymore. look under my updated code how i retrieve the imput. if i change imput="ForestALL" it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Tranq,

i am not exactly sure why you would want to call the width from an array and use DOM when you can simply use CSS to accomplish this with @media instead. correct me if i am wrong, but you're just trying to adjust the width based on values of the current width of the device? this seems like a whole lot of work for what is a simple solution.

use something like to set the appropriate widths depending on the screen widths:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #humid { width: 75%; }
}
```

also, it is likely you're not passing your array properly and it is returning NULL(0). you can check this via a debugger and ensure it is being passed properly. FireFox has a Great built in debugger for this. use CMD/CTRL+SHIFT+K to open the debugger in FireFox.

---

P.S. you are not passing the array properly. you're setting it to change the 'innerHTML' which changes everything inside of the

```
document.getElementById("humid").innerHTML = (arr[0 ]);
```

if you change "(arr[0 ]);" to something like "string" it will replace the value 0 to "string".

Comment: thanks for the reply, i just want this value style="width:75%">  to be the humid value... is that possible?